# Запись в .txt файл результата

Tags: text-to-speech

Здравствуйте, на сайте есть форма для ввода текста голосом, когда вы проговорили текст и он вывелся в поле мне нужно сохранить именно его в .txt файл
уже столько способов перепробовал ничего не получается.

Вот эти строки отвечают за вывод текста на экран

```
<div id="results">
  <span id="final_span" class="final"></span>



  <span id="interim_span" class="interim"></span>
  <p>
</div>
```

Чего только не пробовал ничего не получается, помогите пожалуйста

Comment: Вам ведь код на malbolg нужен, да?

Comment: Нет, хотя бы подсказку как это сделать, через php post не сработало(

Comment: по-моему браузер не имеет доступа к файловой системе, только если загружать файлы. как вариант - отправлять ajax`ом текст, формировать на сервере файл, возвращать браузеру путь до него и грузить уже файл с сервера.

Comment: Запись на стороне пользователя, он жмет button и .txt файл записывается ему на пк, вот только я уже несколько дней мучаюсь и не могу этого сделать, я не особо силен в этом, да и это не просто  сохранить текст из формы, а тут сначала голосом вводится этот текст и именно его нужно сохранить, я нашел где он выводится но сохранить никак не получается, извините если что то не так написал

Comment: Скачиваемые файлы возможно формировать на клиенте в виде блобов, создавать на них URL создавать ссылку на эти URL с атрибутом `download` и эмулировать по ней щёлчок. Никакого участия серверной части не требуется.

Comment: @D-side спасибо большое за совет, не подскажите как это реализовать?

Comment: @ViktorSarkozi сходу откопал [примерчик на jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/koldev/cW7W5/).

Answer (score 0):

Можно воспользоваться [Speechrecognition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechRecognition):

```js
const recognition = window.SpeechRecognition ? new SpeechRecognition() : new webkitSpeechRecognition();

recognition.onerror = error => console.error(error);

recognition.onresult = event => result.innerHTML += event.results[current][0].transcript;

start.onclick = e => recognition.start();
stop.onclick = e => recognition.stop();
```

```html
<div id="results"></div>

<button id="start">Start</button>
<button id="stop">Stop</button>
```